# Extremely bad SVG quality [kivy]

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make svg widgets for my application. I created the SVG's using an app called Figma. The problem is they are extremely poor quality. Why is it like this and is there a solution to fix it?

**Left -** Figma Sketch | **Right -** Kivy Window

[image]

**Python Code**

```
from kivy.graphics.svg import Svg
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter

class SvgWidget(Scatter):

    def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
        super(SvgWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            svg = Svg(filename)
        self.size = svg.width, svg.height

class gui(Widget):     #Main Widget
    pass
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        #PNG Widgets
        self.add_widget(body())
        self.add_widget(headerBox())
        self.add_widget(footerBox())

        #SVG Widgets
        self.add_widget(SvgWidget("./assets/VERSION 1.0.svg", size_hint=(65, 16), pos=(182, 3))) #Version text
        self.add_widget(SvgWidget("./assets/Application Name.svg", size_hint=(225, 26), pos=(8, 228-20))) #Header Text
        self.add_widget(SvgWidget("./assets/LICENSE ACTIVATED.svg", size_hint=(225, 26), pos=(8, 228-32))) #License

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.borderless = True
        self.gui = gui()
        return self.gui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**SVG's -** https://mega.nz/file/E3oUBCwA#p_Ap2qIx4hc3fT0UN19T0P3TiDDry6J_Ss-zOkKzsSU

Comment: Had a look at https://spectrum.chat/figma/help/svg-logo-looking-blurry-on-iphone~313bd6d3-c02c-4ab7-851e-de91f0b44c8a? May not apply but it's one avenue to check.

Comment: I think kivy's svg support just isn't up to what you need right now. In particular, text rendering may not be well supported.

Comment: @paxdiablo This doesn't seem to be the problem, but thanks for trying.

Comment: @inclement I've read off the docs that its highly experimental. Do you know of any GUI frame works that work well with svgs in general?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Nim's fidget gui library. it has an export plugin, directly in Figma. but it's quite rudimentary. Fidget2 is being worked on.
You can also try nimpy, which is a nim to py bridge. create your image with Nim side pixie that draws excellent svg, and read that as an image (or maybe can do that as a GL context?) on the python side (python side imports a shared object .so binary library that Nim creates).
Very Easy interoperability, and Nim is a joy to code in. but it moves the functionality part to Nim, and you'll need to pass drawing data back which I haven't yet tried.